# lsnrctl: command not found in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, sqlplus, oracle18c

I am trying to make connection to Oracle Database 18c XE with sqldeveloper,

but I am getting :

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

So I am trying to start my listener, which I have inside
  */opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/samples*

And I am getting `lsnrctl: command not found`

I am also getting the same message for sqlplus which is inside */opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin*

I know that you are going to say Oracle is not supported for Ubuntu,

but I am really only capable of using Ubuntu..

[CLOSED] I successfully was able to connect to oracle database via sqldeveloper 17.3 by following this link steps and guide:

http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2012/06/trouble-shooting-oracle-11g.html

Comment: The listener is already running, since it generated that error. You don't seem to have your command line environment set up properly - the Oracle directories aren't in your `$PATH`, for example. (`lsnrctl` is in the same directory as `sqlplus`, BTW.) But the actual issue might be much simpler: in your SQL Developer connection configuration change, the radio-button selection from SID to service name and see if it's happier.

Comment: @Alex Poole I tried that by changing radio-button to Service name, but I didn't work. 
Can you tell me how can I set up my directories in $PATH.
Also I am not sure the listener is really working,  because this ORA-12505 Error is inside SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

You need to run following steps to access Oracle executables as documented in [Installation Guide for Linux x86-64](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/setting-oracle-database-xe-environment-variables.html):

```
$ export ORACLE_SID=XE 
$ export ORAENV_ASK=NO 
$ . /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/oraenv

ORACLE_HOME = [] ? /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
The Oracle base has been set to /opt/oracle
```

**`oraenv`** will set PATH to the right setting.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214522/discussion-on-answer-by-pifor-lsnrctl-command-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04).